# How to estimate $\sum_{2 \leq n \leq X} \frac{1}{(\log n)^A} $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

I was wondering how does one estimate 
$$
\sum_{2 \leq n \leq X} \frac{1}{(\log n)^A}?
$$
where $A>0$.
I feel like it should be $\ll \frac{X}{(\log X)^A}$... Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The derivative of $\frac{x}{(\log x)^A}$ is $\frac{1}{(\log x)^A} -  \frac{A}{(\log x)^{A+1}}$ so that $\sum_{n \le x}\frac{1}{(\log n)^A}= \frac{x}{(\log x)^A}+O(\frac{A x}{(\log x)^{A+1}})$, you can't find a much better estimate with  elementary functions, there is a special function [$Li(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) created just for those sums.